# Mysql collate and stored procedures

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with Fruits (Banana,Apple,Pear) and I a query:

```
SELECT name,id FROM fruits WHERE name LIKE ('%ban%');
```

Note that the query contains ban lowercase. The name column is set utf8_collation_ci, so when I run the select, I get my banana. If I put the same query in a stored procedure I wont get it.

I even tried to add COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  to the query inside the stored procedure, but I didn't get my banana again. Why? Should I set everything to Upper() and reconvert all the values in the table?

I'm using mysql.

Edit: This is how HeidiSql wrote the SP

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `getFruits`(IN `inValue` VARCHAR(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'get fruits'
BEGIN
 SELECT name,id FROM fruits WHERE valid=1 AND name LIKE 
    CONCAT('%',inValue,'%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  LIMIT 100 ;
END
```

Comment: i believe its due to the lowercase b. try %Ban% instead of %ban% and let me know how it goes...

Comment: @andrejohannsen217 utf8_collation_ **ci** it means case insensitive.

Comment: -1 for what? Someone didn't read the question correctly.